# Getting Error 500 using okHTTP on android when sending photo to server

Tags: android, python, flask, okhttp

I developed an android app that will take a photo of a digit and send it to the server. In the server the image will go through a neural network and recognize the digit and send the result back. I am getting error 500 instead of the results.

Here is my code for android:

```
//sendbmp is the photo taken from the camera. Its file type is .bmp
sendbmp = Tools.getFocusedBitmap(getApplicationContext(), camera, data, focusBox.getBox());

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    jpgbitmap = sendbmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            mJSONArray = new JSONArray(byteArray);
            base64array = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray,Base64.DEFAULT);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   new Networkconnection().execute();
```

This is the code for Networkconnection() this is where I send the photo to the server. I am using okhttp:

```
private class Networkconnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    String result;
    String new_result;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Response response;
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String byteValue = String.valueOf(base64array);
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("json"), base64array);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build();
        try {
             response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            result = response.body().string();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This is my server side using flask:

```
 @app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def hello_world():
    received_img = request.args.get('body')
    decode_Imge = pic.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(received_img)))
    result = Net.image_function(decode_Imge)
return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Net = Network([784, 100,10])
    for x in range(0,4):
        training_data, validation_data,test_data = load_data_wrapper()
        Net.SGD(training_data, 30, 10, 5.0, test_data = test_data)
   app.run(host ="MyIP") //In my code I actually have my ip address and not "MYIP"
```

Note: When I run the server I am not getting any error. All the classes are on one document for the server. When I print traceback I get the following: 
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 648, in inner fd = int(os.environ['WERKZEUG_SERVER_FD']) File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 425, in __getitem__ return self.data[key.upper()] KeyError: 'WERKZEUG_SERVER_FD'`

Here is the error I get, unfortunately part of the error is blocked by the button:[image: Error 500]

Comment: Please post the traceback/error you are getting.

Comment: Is that okay? I hope the button isn't a issue

Comment: The Flask process must be throwing some sort of error, are you getting a traceback there?

Comment: When I print the traceback I get: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 648, in inner
    fd = int(os.environ['WERKZEUG_SERVER_FD'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 425, in __getitem__
    return self.data[key.upper()]
KeyError: 'WERKZEUG_SERVER_FD'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't sending anything at all to the server. Below is the correct code to send an item to the server using okhttp:

This is how you turn it into base64:

```
//getting img from camera
sendbmp = Tools.getFocusedBitmap(getApplicationContext(), camera, data, focusBox.getBox());
     //converting image to base64
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    jpgbitmap = sendbmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            mJSONArray = new JSONArray(byteArray);
            base64array = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray,Base64.DEFAULT);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is how you send it to the server

```
 Response response;
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String byteValue = String.valueOf(base64array);
        //RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("json"), base64array);//RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"),base64array);

        try {
            MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN
                    = MediaType.parse("text/x-markdown; charset=utf-8");


            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN, byteValue))
                    .build();
             response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            result = response.body().string();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error: " , e.getMessage());
        }
```

This is how you retrieve it in the server using flask:

```
try:
    received_img = request.data
except (Exception) as err:
        traceback.print_exc(err)
//remember that the image we received is in base64, here we are converting it to image
imgdata = base64.b64decode(received_img)
filename = 'some_image.bmp'  # I assume you have a way of picking unique filenames
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(imgdata)

resutl = image_function(filename)
```